# How old is Jack of Shadows?

Tags: jack-of-shadows

Jack is the main character of Roger Zelazny's [*Jack of Shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_Shadows).
I am writing a small game featuring him, and it would help loads if I knew his approximate age.

Even knowing whether he is a few hundred years or a few millenia old would help.

Comment: You should be aware that there may be copyright and/or trademark issues with any public use of Roger Zelazny's characters, storylines, worlds, etc, as it would with any author's works that has not yet passed into public domain (99 years, I think).

Comment: Jack of Shadows was published in 1971, so it’ll arrive in the US public domain in 2066. In most of the rest of the world it‘ll arrive in the public domain in 2065, as copyright typically is 70 years after the author’s death.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jack is old, but we do not really know *how* old.  I would suspect millennia at least, not merely centuries, but that is not established absolutely.  What we do know is that for Jack, a normal human lifetime is quite a brief time for him; when he returns to a former lover, he is surprised to find her an old crone, who had waited her whole adult life for Jack to come back.

However—and here I strong differ with Zeiss Ikon's answer—there is no reason to believe that he is as old as the Darkside itself, and there are actually specific reasons to believe otherwise.  We know from the story that even the powers of the Darkside, who rule various domains and are responsible (in shifts) for maintaining the Shield against the cold of space, have only finite numbers of lives.  Jack certainly has a finite number, and once he has (thanks to Kolwynia) gained total mastery over the Darkside, he plans on repeatedly killing the Lord of Bats, thus exhausting all of his rival's remaining lives.  The permanent slaying of a power (with partial responsibility for the Shield) does not seem to worry him, even though Jack knows that maintaining the Shield is normally a duty that transcends interpersonal rivalries.  He notes at one point that he has, in the past, served with his enemy the Lord of Bats on Shield duty, both of them setting aside their animosity temporarily to do their duty for the planet's survival.  Moreover, he escapes from the Lord of Bats by chagrining the latter into thinking that Jack was needed to defend the Shield.  Jack may have concluded that the tutelary deity responsible for Shield assignments would have found a suitable replacement for the Lord of Bats if the latter were deceased.  The details of the Shield assignments are evidently not understood by Darkside powers themselves (much less the reader), since Jack is able to edit the duty roster without provoking more than puzzled curiosity from the Lord of Bats.  So it seems that the roster of powers responsible for the Shield is not absolutely fixed (although if, as happens late in the novel, all the other powers refuse to take their shifts, the Darkside is in definite danger).  It is entirely possible that new powers may arise, although there is no indication of how this will work.

The specific evidence that Jack is not as old as the Darkside itself comes from his interactions with Morningstar, the (possibly demonic) figure who is (seemingly eternally) waiting for the dawn that does not come to free him from his stony imprisonment.

[image: Morningstar Cover]

Jack has no understanding of why or how Morningstar came to be imprisoned there, or why the sunrise should free him.  It appears that, as far as Jack knows, Morningstar has always been there.  That would make Jack definitely younger than the mechanism that stopped the planet's rotation.

I have based this answer solely on the novel, although there are a few other canonical sources about Shadowjack.  There was a graphic adaptation of a Jack of Shadows adventure (scripted by Zelazny), which can be viewed in its entirety [here](http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/shadow-jack-by-morrow-and-zelazny.html) and [here](http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/shadow-jack-by-morrow-and-zelazny-part.html).  If you are interested in creating a Jack of Shadows game, it is worth noting that the character was featured in Mayfair Games *[Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_(Mayfair_Games))* (a third-party accessory for first edition Advanced Dungeons & Dragons; I can't seem to find a copy online at the moment, but I own a hard copy) also featured stats for Jack and a description of his (ruined) castle Shadow Guard (formerly in the demesne of the Lord of Bats).

Comment: All that would be needed for Jack to be as old as Darkside, yet unaware of how or why Morningstar was frozen to wait the never-coming dawn (and prone to think the latter has been there forever), would be for him to have come into being (or ascended to Power) with the halting of the Earth's rotation -- the same time Morningstar had to have been cursed, else he'd have been freed in no longer than a single night.  If Jack wasn't present at Morningstar's imprisonment, there's no reason he'd know, unless Morningstar told him.

Comment: It's been some years since I last refreshed my memory of that novel, but I do have the impression that it *seemed* as if the established status quo of that world, with the Shield protecting the Darkside and so forth, was something which had begun long before Jack himself was around to pay attention to the details.

Comment: "old enough to think humans have brief lives" could be as low as 400 years. Count Dracula and the Highlander guy think so.

Answer (score 7):

Jack of Shadows is a Darkside Power (the only one not tied to a particular location, he claims).  As such, *he is as old as Darkside*, just as are The Colonel, the Lord of Bats, and the other Powers.  The book doesn't say how long the World has been locked to the sun with the Shield keeping the Darkside from freezing by siphoning off heat that would otherwise burn the dayside -- but it's a long time.

I recall from the book that Jack claims to have hated the Lord of Bats for centuries, so that's a lower bound.  The maintainers of the Shield have had their names in the Book for centuries, as well -- but we just don't know *how many* centuries.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could cite something from the book that said, in effect, that each of the Darkside Powers has been around for as long as there's been a Darkside. (Offhand, I don't recall such a passage, but I don't have a photographic memory.)